# DE_PARA SQL | Alterar valores de uma tabela com base em informações de outra tabela

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Bom dia pessoal. Conseguem me ajudar? Pesquisei anteriormente em outros lugares, mas não encontrei uma solução viável.

Preciso alterar os dados da tabela abaixo de acordo com as novas informações.

Dados importados ao banco:

**TABELA1**

```
COD  | NOMEFUN    |  FUNCAO   |   SALARIO | DEPARTAMENTO | CENTRODECUSTO
-----+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------
001  | THIAGO     | AUXILIAR  |  2.000    |   SOCIETARIO | 09589
002  | LARISSA    | ASSISTENTE|  1.500    |   CONTABIL   | 02222
```

Como deve sair:

**TABELA1**

```
COD  | NOMEFUNC   |  FUNCAO   | SALARIO   | DEPARTAMENTO  | CENTRODECUSTO
-----+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------
001  |  THIAGO    | AUXILIAR  |  2.000    |   SOCIETARIO  | 20.000.002
002  | LARISSA    | ASSISTENTE|  1.500    |   CONTABIL    | 30.000.001
```

Tenho uma planilha fazendo referencia dos Centros de custos para os centros de custos novos.
Criei uma outra tabela com essas informações no banco de dados:

**Tabela 2**

```
ID | OLD.CENTRODECUSTO | NEW.CENTRODECUSTO
---+-------------------+-------------------
1  | 09589             | 20.000.002
2  | 02222             | 30.000.001
```

De que forma eu poderia criar uma regra no banco de dados que altere o valor do **CENTRODECUSTO** na tabela 1  pelos valores da coluna **NEW.CENTRODECUSTO** da tabela 2?

Acredito que estou indo pelo caminho errado e deve haver uma maneira mais simples de atualizar esses valores com um DE_PARA. Mas não consigo encontrar esse caminho.

Comment: Creio que no lugar de uma regra (rule) você deveria criar um gatilho (trigger) que fosse acionado antes de um INSERT ou UPDATE.

Comment: Caso queira rodfar uma atualização é só rodar um UPDATE com um INNER JOIN entre as duas tabelas e modificando o campo para o conteúdo da tabela2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE Tabela1 as t1, Tabela2 as t2 SET
t1.centrodecusto = t2.newcentrodecusto,
WHERE t1.centrodecusto = t2.centrodecusto

essa seria a ideia só ajusta ai os nomes corretos, pois nem todos os servidores